# ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password when connecting to new non-SYSDBA user

Tags: oracle

I'm pretty new to Oracle, I've been trying to logon with a newly created non-SYSDBA user for a while without success.
I'm using Oracle 19c (Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production)

1. I connect to my pdb (orclpdb) as sys with the SYSDBA role
2. CREATE USER USER1 IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD;
3. GRANT CONNECT TO USER1;

I'm using an uppercase user name and password to avoid any doubt.
Then when I try to log as this new user with **any role** and the correct password I receive ORA-01017

[image]

But then if I connect back to the pdb and

GRANT SYSDBA TO USER1;

Now I can log as this new user with the sysdba role:

[image]

If I try to connect with any other role or with the wrong password I then receive ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the PDB when creating the user? As for upper/lower case, it does not matter for the username, but it matters for the password.

Comment: also "GRANT CREATE SESSION TO user1;"

Comment: Make sure you set the correct container when creating the user. To double check, log into the PDB of choice and select * from dba_users where username = 'USER1'. Make sure your client TNS string connects to the correct database.  Lastly, make sure you haven't combined the parameter SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON=FALSE with sqlnet.ora SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER >=12. Check your particular version's docs on the SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER parameter and look at the client compatibility matrix.

Answer (score 0):

-- Create the common user using the CONTAINER clause.
CREATE USER c##test_user1 IDENTIFIED BY password1 CONTAINER=ALL;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO c##test_user1 CONTAINER=ALL;
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-manage-users-and-privileges-for-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1

OR

connect to cdb sqlplus "/as sysdba"

to switch pdb: ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = orclpdb;

to check use:  SHOW CON_NAME

CREATE USER USER1 IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO USER1 container=current;